# isEmpty() always returning true

Tags: android, android-edittext, is-empty

I was making a form on android. While checking for the text fields, I used isEmpty() method to check if there was any text. The problem is, it is always returning true. I'm unable to figure out where I went wrong. Thanks in advance! :)

If any other file is needed, please comment here, I'll add it ASAP.

**AddQuestionActivity.java**

```
import static chipset.quizzy.questionadder.resources.Constants.KEY_QUESTION;
import static chipset.quizzy.questionadder.resources.Constants.KEY_QUESTION_ANSWER;
import static chipset.quizzy.questionadder.resources.Constants.KEY_QUESTION_HINT;
import static chipset.quizzy.questionadder.resources.Constants.KEY_QUESTION_NUMBER;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import chipset.quizzy.questionadder.R;
import chipset.quizzy.questionadder.resources.Functions;
import chipset.quizzy.questionadder.resources.ShowImageActivity;

public class AddQuestionActivity extends Activity {

    Functions functions = new Functions();

    EditText addQuestionNumber, addQuestion, addQuestionAnswer,
            addQuestionHint;
    Button addQuestionImage, addQuestionAdd;
    ImageView addQuestionImageView;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    String picturePath, question, questionNumber, questionAnswer, questionHint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_question);

        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        addQuestionNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionNumber);
        addQuestion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestion);
        addQuestionAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionAnswer);
        addQuestionHint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionHint);
        addQuestionImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionImage);
        addQuestionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionImageView);
        addQuestionAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionAdd);

        questionNumber = addQuestionNumber.getText().toString().trim();
        question = addQuestion.getText().toString().trim();
        questionAnswer = addQuestionAnswer.getText().toString().trim();
        questionHint = addQuestionHint.getText().toString().trim();

        addQuestionAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                functions.hideKeyboard(getApplicationContext(),
                        getCurrentFocus());
                if (functions.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                    if (questionNumber.isEmpty() || question.isEmpty()
                            || questionAnswer.isEmpty()
                            || questionHint.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Enter All Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i(KEY_QUESTION, String.valueOf(question.isEmpty()));
                        Log.i(KEY_QUESTION_ANSWER,
                                String.valueOf(questionAnswer.isEmpty()));
                        Log.i(KEY_QUESTION_HINT,
                                String.valueOf(questionHint.isEmpty()));
                        Log.i(KEY_QUESTION_NUMBER,
                                String.valueOf(questionNumber.isEmpty()));
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                AddQuestionActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Information");
                        builder.setMessage(KEY_QUESTION_NUMBER + " : "
                                + questionNumber + "\n" + KEY_QUESTION + " : "
                                + question + "\n" + KEY_QUESTION_ANSWER + " : "
                                + questionAnswer + "\n" + KEY_QUESTION_HINT
                                + " : " + questionHint + "\n");
                        builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        builder.create();
                        builder.show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        addQuestionImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent addImage = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(addImage, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        addQuestionImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent loadBigImage = new Intent(getApplication(),
                        ShowImageActivity.class);
                loadBigImage.putExtra("picturePath", picturePath);
                startActivity(loadBigImage);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            addQuestionImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addQuestionImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {

            functions.logout(getApplication(), getApplicationContext());

        } else if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_add_question.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/turquoize" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/clouds"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/boxy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addTitle"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/clouds"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        tools:ignore="UselessLeaf" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addQuestionNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/qNo"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/q"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addQuestionAnswer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/qAns"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addQuestionHint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/qHint"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addQuestionImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_click"
                android:text="@string/uQImage"
                android:textColor="@color/turquoize" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addQuestionImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:contentDescription="@string/qImage"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addQuestionAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_click"
        android:text="@string/addQuestionDo"
        android:textColor="@color/turquoize" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this under your `Button onClick(...)` event

```
    questionNumber = addQuestionNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    question = addQuestion.getText().toString().trim();
    questionAnswer = addQuestionAnswer.getText().toString().trim();
    questionHint = addQuestionHint.getText().toString().trim();
```

### Update

Just like so

```
 addQuestionAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

      questionNumber = addQuestionNumber.getText().toString().trim();
      question = addQuestion.getText().toString().trim();
      questionAnswer = addQuestionAnswer.getText().toString().trim();
      questionHint = addQuestionHint.getText().toString().trim();

      ...........
      .............
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, in the onCreate stage itself you are getting the values of the text box and storing it in a variable. Initially the text box would be empty and hence the value would also be empty.

So Modify your onclick Listener code, so that you get the text box value inside the code and then process it. However, also check inside the onclicklistener for empty strings because the user might not have input any value to the textbox. :)

// Edit text instance can be declared in the onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    ....

    addQuestionNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionNumber);
    addQuestion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestion);
    addQuestionAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionAnswer);
    addQuestionHint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addQuestionHint);

    ....
}
```

// Edit Text value getting should be inside onClick

```
public void onClick(View v) {

     questionNumber = addQuestionNumber.getText().toString().trim();
     question = addQuestion.getText().toString().trim();
     questionAnswer = addQuestionAnswer.getText().toString().trim();
     questionHint = addQuestionHint.getText().toString().trim();

     ...
}
```